# Mobile_detect php redirecting to subdomain - Stuck in a redirect loop!

Tags: redirection, theming

I am using the following code in a module for redirection to a subdomain whenever a mobile is detected;

```
<?php

  function mobydetect_init() {
  include("PATH/TO/Mobile_Detect.php");

  $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
  if ($detect->isMobile()) {
    header('Location: http://m.mysite.com');
    drupal_exit();
  }
}
```

However when I go to my site using a mobile I get this error message;

"This web page has a redirect loop."

I have disabled to subdomain from redirecting to the main domain in Aegir. So where's the loop coming from?

Comment: have you tried using chrome / safari web tools to inspect the browser traffic to confirm that the redirect is actually happening? Also how long has it been since you updated the redirect in Aegir? This might be getting cached so you should try cachebusting the url to make sure (ex. http://url/?nocacheplease=true)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your `hook_init` runs on both domains.

You need to check you're not already on the redirected page prior to redirection.

e.g

```
/**
 * Implements hook_init
 */
function mobydetect_init() {
  if($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] != 'm.mysite.com'){
    include("PATH/TO/Mobile_Detect.php");
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    if ($detect->isMobile()) {
      drupal_goto('http://m.mysite.com', array('absolute' => TRUE, 'external' => TRUE));
    }
  }
}
```

Note, `hook_init` doesn't run on cached pages so you may find mobile users aren't redirected on cached pages. You could try using `hook_boot` instead or else offload to the webserver conf.